# Llamar document.ready desde una vista parcial

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc, datatables

Me encuentro trabajando con ASP.NET MVC, JQuery deseo llamar un document.ready desde un ajax que esta en una vista parcial, muestro código:

VISTA PARCIAL

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //$('#message').empty();
        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.guardado) {
                        //Codigo para reinicializar el datatable



                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

INDEX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#proveedores').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Cliente/Index",
            "dataType": "jsonp"
        }
    });
});
```

Deseo llamar ese document.ready desde el if que esta en la otra vista parcial.
¿Como podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `$(document).ready` tantas veces como quieras. Todos se ejecutan cuando el DOM esté listo para ser manipulado. En tu caso no hay problema con hacer

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

     $('form').submit(function (e) {
        ...
     });

  });
</script>
```

Si tu problema es que la vista parcial se inserta antes de que `#form` o `#proveedores` esté en el DOM, entonces podrías editar la pregunta (añadiendo la estructura del html) para ver si corresponde usar delegación de eventos a un elemento superior del DOM.

**EDIT**: la inicialización del datatable puede perfectamente estar dentro de la respuesta de la petición Ajax.

En el ejemplo siguiente hago el supuesto que la instancia de DataTable está inicializada y quieres redeclararla, destruyendo la instancia actual (por ejemplo porque vienen nuevas columnas, anda a saber)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

     $('form').submit(function (e) {
        ...
        $.ajax({
            ....
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.guardado) {

                    // obtengo el DataTable actual y lo destruyo
                    var current_table = $('#proveedores').DataTable();
                    current_table.destroy();

                    $('#proveedores').DataTable({
                        "processing": true,
                        "serverSide": true,
                        "ajax": {
                            "url": "Cliente/Index",
                            "dataType": "jsonp"
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            ...
        });
        ...
     });

  });
</script>
```

Finalmente: uno no llama a un `$(document).ready` desde otro `$(document).ready`. Son listeners para un evento, no funciones que puedas invocar.

Comment: Con el js del index cargo la tabla. Pero cuando de de alta a un registro desde la vista parcial, exactamente desde el botón guardar actualice la tabla volviendola a recargar. Pero el tema es si desde el PV justo en el js en el if pueda llamar a document.ready de la view del index.

Comment: voy a editar mi respuesta para que sea más claro el resultado final

Comment: Es justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: En mi vista Index tengo ese código, y en mi vista parcial tendría la misma función js para que haga lo mismo?

Comment: Ese código tiene que ir en un solo lugar (ya sea en el index o en la PV). Si lo declaras dos veces se gatillará dos veces el evento, y eso tiene resultados impredecibles.

Comment: el tema pasa que en el index tengo el datatable el cual carga cuando se llama a esa vista, el siguiente caso es que desde esa vista por medio de un botón llamo a una vista parcial que lo muestro como popup en el cual doy de alta un nuevo registro y al registrarlo que me actualize(recargar, inicializar) el datatable. Por eso había pensado en dos funciones js una en index y otra en vista parcial

Comment: Un popup o un modal? Coexisten en el mismo documento?

Comment: Lo que se es que un modal es un html que se inyecta en el index en este caso es desde donde se le llama. si es así debería haber una sola función por teoria.